# .Net SQL updateScript

Tags: sql, .net

I am new to .net programming and I have a question.

I need to update table Route based on VehicleID.
The point is I don`t know how to make this query work.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateRouteWithVendorIdAndVehicleTypeId
AS
  (
    SELECT
      vh.VendorId,
      vh.VehicleTypeId,
      r.Id
    FROM Vehicle vh WITH ( NOLOCK )
      INNER JOIN [dbo].Route r WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON r.VehicleId = vh.Id
  )
  UPDATE Route
  SET VehicleTypeId = vh.VehicleTypeId, VendorId = vh.VendorId
  WHERE Id = r.Id
```

How to make this part "`SET VehicleTypeId = vh.VehicleTypeId, VendorId = vh.VendorId`" to be seen outside the first query?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below script

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateRouteWithVendorIdAndVehicleTypeId
  AS
  BEGIN
   UPDATE r
  SET  r.VehicleTypeId = vh.VehicleTypeId
      , r.VendorId = vh.VendorId
  FROM Vehicle vh WITH (NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN [dbo].Route r WITH (NOLOCK) ON r.VehicleId = vh.Id
  END
```

Comment: mark  as right answer,if your query get resolved.. :)